# License dilemma Texas Instruments Code Composer v5 for Stellaris vs MSP430

Tags: msp430, ti-ccstudio, licensing, stellaris

As I read the screenshot below, I have to pick the license for Texas Instruments' Code Composer Studio v5 as follows:

- option 4: to use with a LaunchPad MSP430
- option 3: to use with a LaunchPad Stellaris

[image: License screenshot TI CCSv5]

But I want to use CCSv5 for both Stellaris and MSP430. What license works best or do I have to create two installs, one for each?

Comment: I am not sure whether how the code size limit might affect. Best bet is for you to post on E2E on TI's website since you'll get the right asnwer. By the way, you can develop using completely free tools. MSPGCC for MSP430 is very good, and for Stellaris, Cortex-M3 and M4 is supported by GCC.

Comment: It's true what says @Gustavo, from personal experience I can say that can work with any stellaris without  code limitation or debug implemetation with: `OpenOCD`, `Eclipse CDT` and `CodeSourcery Lite`, especially if you work under Linux,  also with this environment, you can program almost every Cortex-M in the market.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with option 3, for the Stellaris. Finish the setup.
Launch CCS, Then go to Help --> Code Composer Studio Licensing Information --> tab Upgrade --> button Launch License Setup
This time go to option 4.

At this point, both licenses should be installed.

Ref: 
http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/236260.aspx
and
http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/p/209797/742312.aspx